# Converting a matplotlib colourmap to a seaborn colour palette

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have made a colourmap from my chosen colours, however I'd like to convert it to a palette which can be used to 'hue' a seaborn plot. Is this possible, and if so how so?

I have used...

```
cmap = pl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["red","white"],gamma=0.5,N=len(hue))
```

...in order to make my own colourmap, which I know works because it can be applied to a standard [matplotlib.pyplot.scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) successfully, as shown below.

```
plt.scatter(x=[1,2,3,4,5],y=[1,2,3,4,5],c=[5,4,3,2,1],cmap=cmap)
```

[click here to see the output as it won't let me embed an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKX4U.png)

However, I am trying to use seaborn's [swarmplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) function and pass in my colourmap as the hue parameter. Obviously this doesn't work as this parameter requires a palette - hence my question!

I'm not quite sure where to start! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

A seaborn palette is a simple list of colors. You may obtain the colors via

```
cmap(np.linspace(0,1,cmap.N))
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import seaborn as sns

df  =pd.DataFrame({"x" : np.random.randint(0,4, size=200),
                   "y" : np.random.randn(200),
                   "hue" : np.random.randint(0,4, size=200)})

u = np.unique(df["hue"].values)
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["indigo","gold"],gamma=0.5,N=len(u))

sns.swarmplot("x", "y", hue="hue", data=df, palette=cmap(np.linspace(0,1,cmap.N)))

plt.show()
```

[image]