# How to set matplotlib colormap as color palette in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, colormap

How can I set a matplotlib colormap as my color palette in seaborn?

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373881/converting-a-matplotlib-colourmap-to-a-seaborn-colour-palette), but I was unable to implement it:

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('jet')
sns.set_palette(cmap)
```

The second line throws the following error: `from_list() missing 1 required positional argument: 'colors'`

Comment: Looks like you need colors.... as in the `["red","white"]` in the linked question. Then you need to follow the approach in the linked question to fix `sns.set_palette(cmap)`. See the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list) for more detail.

Comment: I'm guessing `["blue","red"]`?

Comment: `map = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('jet',['blue', 'red'])` returns error `TypeError: object of type 'LinearSegmentedColormap' has no len()`

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to follow the approach in the linked question to fix `sns.set_palette(cmap)`, seems to be `sns.set_palette(cmap(np.linspace(0,1,cmap.N)))`.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to specify `N` and `gamma` as well.

Comment: Where does one get information on N and gamma?

Comment: They're discussed in the docs in the link above.

Comment: Right, N is The number of rgb quantization levels. And how does one determine that for the jet colormap?

Comment: Something's really bad about `jet`: `sns.set_palette('jet')` raise a ValueError `No` while `sns.set_palette('viridis')` works just fine :D

Comment: @QuangHoang right! I read somewhere that the Seaborn folks despise jet-- which is fair, but I'm just using it here for a few categories (qualitative) rather than quantitative

Comment: The error you are getting is exactly what the error says: You are not providing enough. The `from_list` method of `LinearSegmentedColormap` takes the name of the colormap and a list of colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to hack through seaborn's, ahem, anti-jet security system is to use `mpl_palette` directly:

```
sns.mpl_palette("jet", 6)
```

The more general approach for "given a matplotlib colormap, how do I get a list of discrete colors?" is to call the colormap object with vector of intensities between 0 and 1:

```
plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, 6))
```

Note that you'll get different results there because seaborn clips the two extreme values, doing something like

```
plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, 8))[1:-1]
```

Also, while I agree that jet is a basically fine source for a small number of discrete colors, unless you really need colors specifically from jet for some reason, I'd suggest looking into the "turbo" colormap, which is constructed basically the same way but with better perceptual properties.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the various proper rainbow-like colormaps that can be found in CMasher: https://github.com/1313e/CMasher